# Deriving UITableView sections from NSFetchedResultsController using "to many" relationship

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My Core Data model looks like this:

```
article <--->> category
```

Is it even remotely possible to use `NSFetchedResultsController` to produce a UITableView that looks something like this?

```
Category 1
  - Article A
  - Article B
  - Article C
Category 2
  - Article A
  - Article D
  - Article E
  - Article F
Category 3
  - Article B
  - Article C
```

Specifically, I'm interested in the (edge?) case where each UITableView section has a unique title (eg, "Category 1", "Category 2"), but the same object can exist in multiple sections (eg, Article A exists in both Category 1 and Category 2).

I have scoured Apple's Core Data docs and have spent two days perusing questions here, but alas, no luck even finding out whether this is possible, let alone how to implement it. Thanks for any help or pointers to a previously answered question. I certainly couldn't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's easy, though there are a million ways to do it.

Your view controller should be the "data source" of the `UITableView`, and returns information about the number of rows there are and then the contents of each individual row.

There is a concept of a "section" in a tableview, you might choose to have one for each category.

For example, you could create an `NSFetchedResultsController` to find the categories you want to display, and use that to populate the table view sections, and then each category would have an articles many-to-many relationship, to populate the rows in each section.

Something like this should get you started (assuming your category and article entities both contain a `title` property):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   // return the number of categories
    [[self.categoryResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // return the title of an individual category
    [[self.categoryResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"title"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // return the number of articles in a category
  MyCategory *category = [self.categoryResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:section];

  return category.articles.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // fetch a cached cell object (since every row is the same, we re-use the same object over and over)
    static NSString *identifier = @"ArticleCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }

    // find the category and article, and set the text of the cell
    MyCategory *category = [self.categoryResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[category.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}
```

You can read the documentation on these methods to figure out how to customise it further.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to ditch `NSFetchResultsController` because I don't see much benefit here but I've not put too much thought into it so I could be wrong.

What you could do is:

1. Perform a fetch request for all `category`'s and place them into an `NSArray`. These will be your sections.
2. For section count return the count of `category`'s
3. For row count return the count of `self.category.articles`

Here's some example code for step 2 + 3

```
// 2
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{
    return [self.categories count];
}

// 3
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return [[[self.categories objectAtIndex:section] articles] count];
}
```