# One-to-Many NSFetchedResultsController with as much rows as the relationship NSSet contains

Tags: sql, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to set up a `tableView` like so:

```
-Family
--Person 1
--Person 2
--Person 3
-Family 2
--Person 1
--Person 2
--Person 3
-Family 3
... etc
```

I have no problems getting the sections populated with the family names:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController:(NSString *)forEntity sortyBy:(NSString*)sortAttribute sectionName:(NSString *)sectionName {

if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:forEntity inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortAttribute ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = 
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:sectionName cacheName:nil];

self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
return fetchedResultsController;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section];
return [[[sectionInfo objects] objectAtIndex:0] name];
}
```

However filling in the rows containing the persons is proving difficult for some reason.

There is a One-to-many relationship active that provides Family with an `NSSet` attribute called "Persons".

**How can I return a correct count on the number of persons in that set and then set the cells accordingly with the Persons' data?**

I tried altering the `numberOfRowsInSection` method in numerous ways but can't seem to find a non-crashing way of accessing the Family. Persons `NSSet` here to count them.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

}
```

Should I be using something other than an `NSSet` or even `NSFetchedResultsController` in a whole?

Important is that I will place "2 `segmentedControls`" above the `tableView`. This will allow some deep filtering but for that to work I need to be able to fill sections and corresponding rows depending on what the user selects to filter on.

For example:
 SegCtrl 1: User selects Family, SegCtrl 2: User selects age. 
This draws a `UITableView` with the available Family names as sections and as rows all the ages of the Persons in that Family.

Comment: Which entity, sort descriptor and section name key path are actually used to create the fetched results controller? In other words, what are the arguments passed to `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController:(NSString *)forEntity sortyBy:(NSString*)sortAttribute sectionName:(NSString *)sectionName` ?

Comment: I altered that method so filtering using the segmented controls would be easier later on. They currently pass on : @"Family", @"name" and @"name" so it performs the fetch on the Family entity, sorts by name and appoints sections by name.

Comment: Sigh.. Hours of searching, you post a question and five minutes later you come across a possible answer. I currently have  Family *myFamily = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:section];
    return myFamily.persons.count; and am then able to convert the NSSet to an Array using the [-allObjects] method. I then get the object at indexpath.row out of that array and get a value using valueForKey:@"age"]; Needs some more testing first (mostly section layout, they look really small and cling together when there is no person entered) but I'll update the answer later tonight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two similar answered questions got me rolling for now:

1. [NSFetchedResultsController and Tables using Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044989/nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-tables-using-relationships/23744220?noredirect=1#comment36506448_23744220)
2. [Deriving UITableView sections from NSFetchedResultsController using "to many" relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335382/deriving-uitableview-sections-from-nsfetchedresultscontroller-using-to-many-re)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
}
```

...do this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count;
}
```

Comment: Hehe, yes that was a crazy remnant from trying out everything I could find! Thanks for pointing that out :)